# How do I use perl regex to extract the digit value from '[1]'?

Tags: regex, perl

My code...

```
$option = "[1]";
if ($option =~ m/^\[\d\]$/) {print "Activated!"; $str=$1;}
```

I need a way to drop off the square brackets from $option. $str = $1 does not work for some reason. Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($option =~ m/^\[(\d)\]$/) { print "Activated!"; $str=$1; }
```

Or

```
if (my ($str) = $option =~ m/^\[(\d)\]$/) { print "Activated!" }
```

Or

```
if (my ($str) = $option =~ /(\d)/) { print "Activated!" }
```

..and a bunch of others. You forgot to [capture your match with ()'s](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches).

EDIT:

```
if ($option =~ /(?<=^\[)\d(?=\]$)/p && (my $str = ${^MATCH})) { print "Activated!" }
```

Or

```
my $str;
if ($option =~ /^\[(\d)(?{$str = $^N})\]$/) { print "Activated!" }
```

Or

```
if ($option =~ /^\[(\d)\]$/ && ($str = $+)) { print "Activated!" }
```

For ${^MATCH}, $^N, and $+, [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

I love these questions : )

Answer (score 7):

To get $1 to work you need to capture the value inside the brackets using parentheses, i.e:

```
if ($option =~ m/^\[(\d)\]$/) {print "Activated!"; $str=$1;}
```